# Some module conflicts with views?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create some views with drupal 7.53.

When I try to create view, I set title, type of content, sorted by, and then click save and exit.

Ok, now, add view screen remains and I can't do anything.
I uninstalled jquery update module, jquery easing, taxonomy menu field, nicemenus,  superfish, submenutree and libraries. But the problem remains: view doesn't create.

Some other module that conflicts with views module? I don't know what can I do!

Comment: Open your browser's console and see if any errors pop up when you click save.

Comment: When creating or editing a view, be sure to click the `Save` button. Could you post a screenshot of your views settings?

Comment: Did you flush/clear the cache?

Comment: The modules you have listed actually do not conflict with views. But have you installed the dependency for views: ctools? https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools

Comment: @Volker of course he has, you can't enable a module without installing the dependant module. Perhaps the better question would be to make sure the Ctools folder has not been deleted from `/sites/all/modules`, but if this was the case, he would be getting a drupal error message.

Comment: Try using a different web browser or use Incognito Window just to make sure there isn't a browser app blocking some js or something.

Comment: @NoSssweat you're right, that would have been the better question.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't debug your site from here, and providing guesses isn't something that suits Q+A. Please add some more details to the question when you've had a chance to do some debugging and have more information, and flag for reopening. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the problem is with internet explorer. With google chrome views works correctly. So, 9'm using google chrome.